# Single @Repository vs multiple @Repository - S3 and elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring

I am writing a document repository application that receives word documents via a folder on the filesystem and stores them in Amazon S3. At the moment I have a `@Service` and a `@Repository` as follows:

```
@Service
public class DocumentService {

    @Autowired
    DocumentRepository documentRepository;

    public void storeDocument(Document document) {

        documentRepository.store(document);
    }

    public Document retrieveDocument(String id) {

        return documentRepository.retrieve(id);
    }
}

@Repository
public class DocumentRepository {

    @Autowired
    AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    public void store(Document document) {

        amazonS3Client.putObject("word-bucket", document.getId(), document.getFile());
    }

    public Document retrieve(String id) {

        S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("word-bucket", id));

        Document document = new Document(id, s3Object.getObjectContent());

        return document;
    }
}
```

I have to extend the application such that when a new document is encountered, the text body is indexed by elasticsearch. It seems like I have two options to achieve this:

1. Extend the existing DocumentRepository so that it communicates with both S3 and elastic search
2. Create a new repository called DocumentIndex and make the DocumentService call both documentRepository.store and documentIndex.index

Is the idea of a repository to associate it with a single "store" e.g. database, filesystem? If so then the second option would appear to be the most suitable.

Thanks in advance for any pointers.